# Handle different view controllers within an application: creating Custom Content View Controllers

Tags: ios, architecture, uiviewcontroller

During application development I have problems to support the right application architecture. This is true for the application I'm currently developing. In particular, I need to support an architecture like the following.

[image]

As you can see, the `MainViewController` is the main controller for the application and has to manage different controllers within the application lifecycle. In this case `MainController` is a sort of centralized controller (a subview of its view stays always on front, think to it as a menu view) that manages the different states of the application (e.g. LOGIN_AREA, HOME_AREA, etc.).

In the following I wrote some consideration to achieve the above architecture.

Since `MainViewController` needs always to display its view's subview in front of other views (`UIviewControllerX`'s views), I set it as the `rootViewController`.

Since `MainViewController` has to be accessed by the other controllers (e.g `UIViewControllers1`), they need to have a (weak) reference it.

`MainViewController` has a public method to manage the application state. It store the current controller and add to its view the selected controller view as its subview. For example:

```
- (void)manageController
{
   if(currentState == LOGIN_AREA)
   {
      self.currentController = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
   }

   // other stuff here...

   [self.view addSubView:self.currentController.view];
}
```

The above pattern seems to work but I'm not pretty sure if it could be correct. In addiction, the situation gets complicated if a `UIViewController` (e.g. `UIViewController1`) has to be a `UINavigationController`.

I've read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). In particular, I found interesting the section [Creating Custom Content View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW1) but I havent' found any example to create a customized one.

So, my question is the following.

Could you give me suggestions to achieve the following architecture? Or could you give me some tips to develop a custom content view controller?

Comment: It seems you are confusing UIViewControllers and UIViews?

Comment: Maybe my question is unclear. Why do you think about this confusion? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested in.

To implement a similar machanism there are two different ways.

1) Implement a custom content container. It's a complex task but it's possible. For more info read [writing-high-quality-view-controller](http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.com/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html)

2) Use the new iOS 5 API. For more info it's possible to read **Implementing a Container View Controller** section in [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope it helps.