# What is the recommended way to enforce a specific rootViewController in a custom UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm building an iPhone SDK that will be used by other iPhone developers.

The main use of this SDK will be to present a UI that will enable the user to complete a certain process.

This UI should be wrapped inside a UINavigationController because it is composed from several UIViewControllers that form the process.

I want that the developers that will use my SDK will initialize my custom UINavigationController and then present it however they want.

I want to enforce that the rootViewController of my custom navigation controller will be a specific ViewController from the SDK, and developers won't be able to initialize it with a different rootViewController.

What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a class method to instantiate your view controller:

```
+(MyViewController*)myViewController {
    MyViewController* = myViewController = [[MyViewController* alloc] init];
    myViewController.rootViewController = [[MyDesiredRootViewController alloc] init];
    return myViewController;
}
```

The developers would than use this method to initialize your view controller and all the initialization work would be hidden from them.

Comment: I really prefer this way and this is what I actually impelented

Answer (score 2):

You should not subclass `UINavigationController` as written in Apple doc.

> This class is not intended for subclassing. Instead, you use instances
>   of it as-is in situations where you want your application’s user
>   interface to reflect the hierarchical nature of your content.

If you iOS 5, use the new containment API for `UIViewController`s.

[Implementing a Container View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController)

Using this approach you could enforce your root controller and leave it hidden to the user.

If iOS 5 is not available see my previous answer on it [Handle different view controllers within an application: creating Custom Content View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262469/handle-different-view-controllers-within-an-application-creating-custom-content).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could fail the initialization if the rootViewController is a different class

```
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootController
{
    if(![rootController isKindOfClass:[YourRootViewController class]])
        return nil;

    //Do default init stuff

}
```

Comment: I'd rather not fail it, but force it to be what I want. I don't want the developers to even know about the "internal" viewController.

Comment: Omar, the navigation controller should not be subclassed since strange things could happen..

Comment: yes you are 100% right, he should extend the UIViewController and use UIViewController containment properties to implement his own navigation controller